# How to use regex to remove various tags that appear either side of word in a string?

Tags: python, regex

say that

```
strng= 'I have to get to the <Color:D010644> maroon <Color:D010644> building before noon'
```

How do I use regex to transform this string to

```
strngNew =  'I have to get to the maroon building before noon'
```

What makes this tricky is that the digits in the tag change among the lines, and the number of digits also vary. So in the example above, the digits were 'D010644' but in another line it could be 'JJD93JD93J999333'.

So I need the regex operation to be general to all variations of this.

However, the tag name ( which is 'Color' in the example above) remains constant.

Comment: How _you_ solve the problem is _by writing some code_. If that code doesn’t work despite your best efforts and debugging attempts, then edit it into your question here and ask for help, but not without those preconditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to filter out the tags:

```
import re

text = 'I have to get to the <Color:D010644> maroon <Color:D010644> building before noon'

result = re.sub(r'(<Color:)\w+(> )', '', text)

print(result)  # I have to get to the maroon building before noon
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with standard library too:

```
str = 'I have to get to the <Color:D010644> maroon <Color:D010644> building before noon'
new_string = ' '.join([elem for elem in str.split(' ') if not elem.startswith('<Color')])
print(new_string)

>>> I have to get to the maroon building before noon
```